# Trouble accessing Image from instance of UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm following this tutorial with some modifications for my project:  http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/

I'm trying to get the instance of UIImageView that IB creates for me.

Here is a screenshot of my IB:

[image]

I have a custom class called FeedViewCell that is to contain an UIImageView.  Here is the cellForItemAtIndexPath code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[postPhotos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

The problem is that UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];  comes back as nil.  Using the viewWIthTag method seems weird to me anyway, but in the debugger I see no sign that imageView is a subview of UICollectionViewCell.  If you look at this debug screen, you can see that the cell doesn't appear to have any UIImageView subviews:

[image]

However I see 2 UIImageViews as subviews of the CollectionView.

So it seems to be that I'm doing something wrong in IB.  This isn't surprising as I always seem to struggle with IB (looking at code at least I can see what's going on).

Thanks for any suggestions!

update:  I gave up on using IB to hook in the ImageView and tried creating it in code as below: 
http://cl.ly/QFxs

The images don't display properly.  If you look in the screenshot (debugger) though, you will see images and imageViews are both valid objects though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to use tags in this situation.  You can create a UIImageView property in FeedViewCell wire it up in interface builder and then access it in

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

For Example

// in the FeedViewCell

```
    @interface FeedViewCell  : UICollectionViewCell

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

    @end
```

// in the controller

```
    - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

        FeedViewCell *cell = (FeedViewCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[postPhotos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        return cell;
    }
```

Open up storyboard then click the assistant editor button which will bring up the another window.  Open the feedViewCell.h there and ctrl+click on the imageView and drag it to the .h file that will give you a menu to create the outlet.  You can give it the name to the imageView Property.  That should be it.
[image]

Check out this link for more info
http://klanguedoc.hubpages.com/hub/IOS-5-A-Beginners-Guide-to-Storyboard-Connection

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling `self.collectionView registerClass...`, then you need to remove it. Storyboards handle this registration automatically.