# viewWithTag returns nil when initializing a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Just getting started with `UICollectionView`. I've used IB to create a simple `UICollectionView` in a `UIViewController`. It scrolls horizontally with paging. I placed a simple `UICollectionViewCell` inside the `UICollectionView`. I set the reuse identifier for the cell.

I placed a `UILabel` with a tag of 100 inside the `UICollectionViewCell`.

In `viewDidLoad`, I call:

```
[_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Thing"];
```

Later I attempt to initialize the cell like so:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Thing" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    nameLabel.text = @"Bogus";

    return cell;
}
```

When I run the app, the view loads correctly; I can scroll horizontally through the 2 cells. I see the ugly green color identifying each cell.

However, the `viewWithTag` method returns `nil` and therefore the nameLabel text is not set.

Why?

Note that I also tried defining a custom subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` and calling registerClass with it. In IB, I change the cell class to the custom subclass and I bind the `UILabel` to the `UILabel` outlet in the subclass.

But this also does not work. (I would prefer to avoid the custom subclass approach anyway because it does not seem necessary to define classes just to hold `IBOutlets`.)

I'm thinking that I'm missing something obvious here.

Similar problem described here:

[Trouble accessing Image from instance of UICollectionViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655252/trouble-accessing-image-from-instance-of-uicollectionviewcell)

Comment: Where do you create the UILabel?

Comment: The UILabel is configured in Interface Builder. I don't expect to alloc it in code. I was thinking that viewWithTag should retrieve the created instance. This is how it works with UITableView.

Comment: Have you assigned the reuseIdentifier for prototype CollectionViewCell in your nib?

Comment: @chandu Yes, dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier returns a valid cell. If I have a mismatch here, then the app will crash.

Comment: I think your collectionView cell is not made from your prototype in your nib, rather it is creating a cell from RegisterClass method. You have to use registerNib method.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Remove the registerClass line. You are doing it on storyboard, so you don't need it.

Comment: Why would they make the default behavior to confuse the sh*t out of developers?? Don't most people use the storyboard???

Answer (score 1):

try it

`UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];`

Update:

You can look the cell's hierarchy and all its subview's tag :`[self showAllSubView:cell] ;`, can you find your label with tag 10 ?

```
- (void)showAllSubView:(UIView *)view
{
    for (UIView * subView in [view subviews]) {
        NSLog(@"%@, tag:%d", subView, subView.tag) ;
        [self showAllSubView:subView] ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Had tried that too - did not work. Tried again for kicks - still no luck

Comment: @Daniel I have updated my answer, it may help to find if the label is on the hierarchy of cell.