# UICollectionView cell.ViewWithTag returning nil for UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uilabel, viewwithtag

This label seems to return nil, even though I have the reuseIdentifier and tag set properly.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var identifier: String = "CollectionCell"
    var cell: UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell

    // Configure the cell


    //save till later, when images are actually present

    //var cellItem1 = hostManager[indexPath.row * 2]

    let label:UILabel = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    return cell

}
```

The program breaks where the label is set = to the viewWithTag. I have no custom class set for the cell, just the prototype. The tag is set on the storyboard. Getting an error "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION...". Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Just do this for debugging :- http://stackoverflow.com/a/21399753/2714702  ... and check whether you are getting the view tag in the sub-views. according to that you should proceed.

Answer (score 6):

Try removing this line from viewDidLoad:

```
self.collectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just created a sample project with your code and for me it works. Although you shouldn't force unwrap.

Make sure you have the correct setup in your storyboard:

[image]

Check if your collectionViewCell is setup correctly:

[image]

And set the tag of your label:

[image]

Here is the [sample project](http://rolandkeesom.com/TestApp.zip)

Comment: your sample project works fine for me. I recreated a VC and put a CollectionView in it, hooked it up to delegate and datasource, set my tag on the label and few other buttons I have in the cell, however, I still get the error