# Can't access cell subviews Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have this function inside my UICollectionView Class:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MoreCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell

    if let icLab = cell.viewWithTag(491) as? UILabel{
        icLab.text = moreitems[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].title
    }else{
        println("Couldnt find label")
    }

    // Same code for imageView
```

The rest of the `UICollectionView` is fine because it does display the cells properly on the screen, as well as the initially set label text ("Label")

But I just can't seem to access the subviews inside. Here is how they're set up:

[image]

And I do have the Tags and the Cell ID set up correctly.

Has anyone any idea why it keeps printing `Couldn't find Label`

Screen looks like this:

[image]

Obviously the placeholder image and label is not being edited.

Comment: ys just same thing questioned by here...but nothing work...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31781933/uicollectionview-cell-viewwithtag-returning-nil-for-uilabel/31782061#comment51493870_31782061

Comment: Did you check the label's tag number?I just replicate it and it worked fine.

Comment: Nope, the Tags are correct, I double checked too many times

Answer (score 1):

From apples's document

> Installed views are added to the view hierarchy. Uninstalled views are not added.

Choose the label and select '`Installed`'
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is an easily missed little trap!!! Especially when you are trying to work on various Size Class. Check this document https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/EnableAndDisableViews.html

Answer (score 0):

From the [UICollectionViewCell documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewCell_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UICollectionViewCell/contentView) :

> var contentView: UIView { get }
>
> When configuring a cell, you add any custom views
>   representing your cell’s content to this view. The cell object places
>   the content in this view in front of any background views.

So you must look for your views inside cell's contentView and not cell itself

```
if let icLab = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(491) as? UILabel{
    icLab.text = moreitems[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].title
}else{
    println("Couldnt find label")
}
```

Comment: Go ahead and debug view hierarchy, there you should be able to locate your missing views. Also are you sure that view with tag 491 is actually a UILabel ?

Comment: Positive the tag is correct, you can see in the screenshot anyway. I'm not sure how to debug the view hierarchy, I'll look it up

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/using_view_debugger/using_view_debugger.html might be helpful

Comment: @GregPeckory On more thing to try : look up directly in cell's first subview `cell.subviews[0].viewWithTag(491)` , if that work then its surly a bug :)