# JTAppleCalendar cell inside TableView ? in Swift 3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uicollectionview, jtapplecalendar

Im using `JTAppleCalendar` -> https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar  Calendar plugin and I want to place ColectionView Cells inside TableView cell , and I want to show there each cell inside added events with title (inside tableview cell) , but when I connecting outlets gives me;

> error: Illegal Configuration: The tableView outlet from the ViewController to the UITableView is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.

How can I fix it ?

CellView.swift

```
import JTAppleCalendar

class CellView: JTAppleCell {
    @IBOutlet var selectedView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var dayLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var Label: UILabel!
}
```

Cell.Swift

```
import UIKit

class Cell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var label : UILabel!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)


    }
}
```

ViewController.Swift

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


  extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return  1
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return  5
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell

            cell.label?.text = String(indexPath.row)

            return cell
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

My Screen under below;

[image]

Comment: if you create a new github issue, and upload a small zip file of the problem there, i can help. Then i'll return here to put the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom class of CollectionViewCell and take IBOutlets on it. now you have taken customCell's views IBOutlets in ViewController's class.

OR

Using tag property you can link that view with cell. as below in cellForItemAtIndexPath.

```
let label:UILabel = cell.viewWithTag(101) as! UILabel // 101 tag need to set in storyboard related view
```

**How to assign tag to view**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31782616/3901620

Comment: then still this problem occurs .

Comment: I added my tableview codes can you show me how can I fix it ?

Comment: cell's label where declared ?

Comment: I added Cell.Swift